# Segmentation Fault in C++: sorted linked list

Tags: c++, function, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I m writing a function to insert a number in a sorted linked list in C++. However, I am getting "Segmentation Fault" when I run it. Can anyone explain why it is so?

```
    Node * insertInSorted(Node * head, int data)
{
    Node * curr = head;
    Node * a = new Node(data);
    
    while(curr->next->data < a->data || curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    Node * temp = curr->next;
    
    curr->next = a;
    a->next = temp;
    
    return head;
}
```

Comment: `curr->next != NULL*`is too late. Learn how to use a debugger [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: To expand on @S.M's answer, you are accessing the property `data` of `curr->next` prior to checking, whether `next` is even valid. As such, at the end of the list, you are accessing a NULL pointer, which leads to the segfault. Simply switch the conditions around and the problem should disappear (due to short circuiting conditions)

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I tried doing what you suggested, but I am still getting Seg Fault.

Comment: Well, that was just the most obvious error. How about you run the source file through a debugger of your choice and tell us, where the segfault actually occurrs?
If you watch the involved variables carefully, you might already figure out the problem yourself.

As a little additional hint, you may want to make sure, that 'curr' does not end up being 'NULL' at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `while(curr->next->data < a->data || curr->next != NULL)`

That is obviously wrong. The condition you want is:

`while(curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < a->data)`

1. The next node must exist *and*
2. Must have `data` smaller than the `data` you are inserting.

The function still wouldn't work correctly (you never insert anything before `head`, even if that's where the insertion should happen), but at least your crash should be gone.